# eso-pic colorgrid overwriting pdfpages page

Tags: pdfpages, eso-pic

this may be really obvious but I'm trying to use pdfpages to annotate a pdf "form". To help with filling it in, I'm trying to put a grid on the page.

The following code places a grid on the page but it covers the pdf so I cant see what I'm trying to fill.

What am I doing wrong? (MWE with `\includepdf ..somepdf` replaced with any pdf file/page)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[colorgrid,texcoord,gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1-1]{"/home/me/somepdf"}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage[grid,
      gridcolor=red!20,
      subgridcolor=green!20,
      %texcoord,
      gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}
```

## Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[grid,
  gridcolor=red!20,
  subgridcolor=green!20,
  %texcoord,
  gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{snifs_fov}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @HarishKumar. As ever your answer works perfectly, and as ever, I'm not quite sure why it works. Appreciate the help.